# File handler behavior in case there is no space left on Disk

Tags: file, unix

There is a process running on our server, which writes well defined messages in a file. The process of writing is like one message per line and then next message in next line.

But we saw recently there were 2 message in a single line. During same time we saw that the disk space has got completely full at that time. But then later space was made available, the writing into file followed the expected pattern.

Can this double message in a single line could be because previous message was not completely dumped into file and when space was made available, writing started from last position till which write had been done previously ?

All I want to know is how any process writing into any file will behave in such cases. How does file handler meant to write behave in such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's as you say.

Seems pretty obvious. There was not enough space for a trailing newline, at a certain point in time. Then space was opened up, and future messages started being appended to the file again.

There's no "way" that the "file handler" is supposed to "behave" when you run out of disk space. If you try to write a byte to disk, and there is insufficient space on that disk, the write will fail. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks a lot . But this has to be a rare scenario , in a way that first message was completely written other than trailing newline

Comment: Can I get to know , something more about it from somewhere, as people don't agree with me that this can be one those rare cases.

Comment: @Invictus: There is nothing more to know. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ok ..Thanks , at least i found someone who thinks like me on this.

Comment: @Invictus: Thinks like _what_?

Comment: It is not as obvious as you make it sound. I am not sure what OP is using to make actual writes, but normally you would know how much you have written, and once the space is availble, resume writing from already written bytes. Of course, if someone was to simply discard return values and retry the whole message...

Comment: @SergeyA: That's logic you write into your program. It's completely within your control. It has nothing to do with the computer's "file handler" and is not "a rare scenario" that you can "get into". I reckon half the problem here is that the OP is grossly unclear.

Comment: I am not unclear about it , yes i agree with Sergey that we should know , how mch we have written and then resume from same. And also agrees with LRIO that yes , that has nothing to do with my question as it was all about file Handler.

Comment: 100% agree, with a quirk )) For instance, if you are using C++ file streams, this will be happening automatically for you. So if the OP is using streams (question tagged with C++) the behaviour would be strange and not explained.

Comment: @Invictus, who are 'we'? We as SO commenters have no idea how much you have written. How exactly are you writing?

Comment: This writing takes place in other part of application , which is not under me but i uses that data ( so i wrote we ) . I will further check what mechanism is exactly used by them to write this as i do not have access to their code. This is why i asked behavior of file handler in such cases , if they have any special handling here .

Comment: @SergeyA Btw do you expect such cases can happen in case of C file stream ?

Comment: @Invictus, once again, I can only re-iterate what LRiO have said. There is no specific withing 'file handler' - whatever you mean by that. The behaviour is very simple. Low-level write() function (I assume you are on some sort of *nix, I have no idea about Windows, but suppose, it is more or less alike) will write as much as it can, return the number of actual bytes written and set errno to the reason why less bytes were written. Whatever happens after it depends on the actual write mechanism.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks again for your explanation . I will revisit the mechanism used to write in our case .

Comment: So then you were asking us for information about _your_ code? Odd!